# Highcharts gauge: Circle points on gauge

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, gauge

I am trying to achieve [this effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHPaa.png) in Highcharts.

I have successfully modified a Solid Gauge to have 1 circle point on the arc but this was done with specifying the `threshold` of the chart to just below the actual value and have the dot extend to just past the actual value. I have attempted using Solid Gauge and the regular Gauge with Dials modified to appear on the arc but Dials cannot be rounded, as far as I know.

[Example of a Gauge with modified Dials](http://jsfiddle.net/4peetbqL/17/)

```
plotOptions: {
    gauge: {
    dial: {
        baseLength: '100%',
      baseWidth: 10,
      radius: '100%',
      rearLength: '-90%',
      topWidth: 100,
    },
    pivot: {
        radius: 0,
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it by adding a series per dot on a Solid Gauge and adding a `threshold` per series instead of inside `plotOptions`. `threshold` is not in the API documentation for `series.solidgauge`...

Comment: Could you post the solution for that? I am having the same problem, (i am trying to make those points as circles) but i don't really understand how can i achieve that.

Comment: Unfortunately this was on a client's project that has long since ended and I no longer have access to the source. As my solution states, you will add a series for each dot you want to plot then adjust the threshold on each series to be just beneath the value you plotted. I believe I ended up adding and subtracting .4 from the value so the dot sits on the correct value. I had to guess how to do this since the highcharts documentation did not specify threshold could be defined per series